# Make menu in CSS like in the picture

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have questions about how to reproduce the following:
[image]

I would like to know how I should proceed to make this menu conform to the picture above. I do not want anything ready, but a way to get the expected result.

So far, I have the following code:

```css
body{
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}
nav:after{
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block; 
  list-style: none;
}
nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  padding: 20px 15px 15px 15px; 
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav li a:hover {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
nav li a:hover:after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 10px solid yellow;
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 54px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry but your question is likely to be closed as Stack Overflow is predominantly an English language site.

Comment: Desculpe, mas sua pergunta provavelmente será fechada, já que o Stack Overflow é predominantemente um site em inglês.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made the registration of the question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask but she did not go to the Portuguese site but to the English site.

Comment: I translated my question to English...

Comment: Do you have some link to the site you have the screen from? That's very easy to copy frontend solutions using dev tools in your browser.

Comment: No. This image was done by a freelancer designer and I need to run this in HTML / CSS

Comment: This what you're going for? http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/dNjzmZ

Comment: Yes that's what I needed to do! Thanks a lot bro!

Comment: @MichaelCoker Now, how do i make like this: http://imgur.com/5hSjNEF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution should be helpful

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
  position: relative;
}

nav:after {
  content: '';
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: .6em;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 .5em;
}
nav li:last-child a:before {
  display: none;
}

nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.6em 0.6em 0.7em 0.6em;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1;
}
nav li a:before {
  content: "|";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 1.6em;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-4%);
          transform: translateY(-4%);
  line-height: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: #fff;
}
nav li a:after {
  display: none;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ffaf1a;
  z-index: 2;
}

nav li a:hover {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
nav li a:hover:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 23</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 345</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 44567</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Menu 567889</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Woooow man! That's right! Thank yo! Can you help me with another problem? I need to create the dropdown list menu, like this image: http://imgur.com/5hSjNEF

Comment: @GabrielBontorin create a new question, explaining your issue in detail, don't ask to answer another question within the current one.

Comment: @alljamin I will do this. Thx bro!

Comment: I love when I see someone using flex! @jseezo <3

Answer (score 0):

Stick the elements out of the bottom of the  nav with this code: https://jsfiddle.net/d379Lagm/

```
body{
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
  outline: 5px solid #000;

}


nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}

nav li {
  display: inline-block; 
  list-style: none;
}
nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  padding: 20px 15px 15px 15px; 
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
nav li a:hover {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;

}
nav li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: transparent;
  height: 5px;
  content: "";
  transform: translateY(950%);
}
nav li a:hover:after {
  background: yellow;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But that's not what I need... I need to get a "white border" after the menu and after this "white border", the black border. And on this black border, would be the menu hover option...

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.

Comment: Thanks bro! I've already made this change here: http://jsfiddle.net/gxukz/42 now I need to do something like this: http://imgur.com/5hSjNEF

Answer (score 0):

Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/97cyvmcy/

Simply, just use two linear gradients to achieve the desired effect:

One with red and yellow stripes:

```
li a:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 0%, red 90%, yellow 90%, yellow 100%);
}
```

And the other with black and white stripes at the bottom:

```
nav:after {
  content:' ';
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, black 0%, black 50%, white 50%, white 100%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro! I've already made this change here: http://jsfiddle.net/gxukz/42/ now I need to do something like this: http://imgur.com/5hSjNEF